# TeamCity Custom nuget server

Tags: teamcity, nuget-server

I was wondering if I can use my own private nuget server in TeamCity that requires authentication. I know that TeamCity offers a built-in nuget server but I dont want to use this as I have dozens of packages on my own server already.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an external nuget feed for any steps that use nuget.exe (install/publish) steps.

You can provide credentials for the external feed using a build feature called [Nuget Feed Credentials](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/NuGet+Feed+Credentials)